# Datatables is not fitting in screen

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatable

I have a [datatable](https://datatables.net/) defined like that:

```
 <html><body>
 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table class="table responsive table-togglable table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-toggle="true">ID</th>
        <th >Usuario</th>
        <th >Objeto</th>
        <th >Id del Objeto</th>
        <th class="none">Antes</th>
        <th class="none">Despues</th>
        <th >type</th>
        <th >Creaci&oacute;n</th>
        <th >Actualizaci&oacute;n</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>2165</td>
        <td> - </td>
        <td>PersonReferences</td>
        <td>3802973</td>
        <td> -  </td>
        <td> Large Text </td>
        <td>created</td>
        <td>2016-05-11 17:07:23</td>
        <td>2016-05-11 17:07:23</td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="http://rh.dev/assets/materialize/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rh.dev/assets/js/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rh.dev/assets/js/datatables/extensions/responsive.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $('.table-togglable').DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });
</script>
```

The 2 columns that are classed with "none" works. When I click on row, it shows those 2 long values.

Thing is I can see the four first columns, half of the fifth, and I can't see all others.

Any idea what's going on???

EDIT:

Here is my generated  tag:

```
<table class="table responsive table-togglable table-hover dataTable no-footer dtr-inline collapsed" id="DataTables_Table_0" role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info" style="width: 2446px;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your html, you lack the tag `tbody`, change your code by this...

```
<table class="table responsive table-togglable table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th data-toggle="true">ID</th>
    <th >user</th>
    <th >object_type</th>
    <th >object_id')</th>
    <th class="none">old_value</th>
    <th class="none">new_value</th>
    <th >type</th>
    <th >created_at</th>
    <th >updated_at</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($logs as $log)
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td> text </td>
        <td>text </td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>{{ $log->created_at }}</td>
        <td>{{ $log->updated_at }}</td>
    </tr>

@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you use `responsive: true` you sholud import the css responsive

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.2/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/48/

Comment: mmmm.. Now I have green switch on the left, but the problem still remains... it might be a style issue...

Comment: I can see in my <table> tag: style="width: 2446px;" but I don't know where it come from... when I remove it, it works!

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro you have the same problem in my jsfiddle??

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro then the problem is for you element parent of the table, Responsive inherits the width of the parent tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111807/discussion-between-cmedina-and-juliatzin-del-toro).